# Other method in thread executing before run method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

In my program I am calling the thread to do some job but the other method of thread class executes before the run method.

```
public class Verify extends JFrame implements Runnable 
{
    long Local_cid;
    String local_path;
    static boolean isIntialised=false;
    JProgressBar bar;

    final static ArrayList<Long> ContactList=new ArrayList<>();
    final static ArrayList<Long> Scanned=new ArrayList<>();
    static boolean flag=true;
    static boolean Duplicate_flag=true;
    boolean[] flags=new boolean[6];

    public Verify(long ID,String path) 
    {
        Local_cid=ID;
        local_path=path;

    }

    public boolean[] Return_Flag()
    {

        System.err.println("Verify Id");
        return  flags;

    }

    public void dispose_Frame()
    {
        System.err.println("Executing First");
        dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        System.err.println("This should Executed First");

    }

}
```

When I call this thread via start call the output is as follows:

> Verify Id
>
> Executing First
>
> This should Executed First

Comment: how are you invoking thread?

Comment: Verify verify=new Verify(id,path);
new Thread(verify).start();

Comment: few more lines please, i just want to see if in case any other line of your code is invoking those methods

Comment: it would be easy , if you have Thread name as part of SOP and provide thread name while creating it. Wil help to solve your problem yourself :) . it may be called by different thread and creating illusion that called first

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the Java coding standard style guides, it will make it much easier for people to read.

There is nothing in the code you have posted that calls `Return_Flag()` so you must be calling it somewhere else - probably from the code that creates the thread in the first place.

Run is only called once the thread is started, and other threads are still running at the same time and can call whatever methods they like in whatever order they like...

Answer (score 0):

I'm 100% sure that you are calling those methods somewhere in your code before actually starting the thread. Just look more careful and you will find it.